# Adding class object to an array with class function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object

I'm trying to add an object to an object array with class function without any STL function.

```
Class Object
{
   int number;
   string name;

   void addObj(Object objects[]);
}

Object::addObj(Object objects[])
{
   /*add this object to the array   */
}
```

I tried to initialize the array in the main then I change the value. 
Assume I have an global variable counter.

```
int main()
{
   Object obj; //
   Object objects[10] = obj; 
}

Object::addObj(Object objects[])
{
   objects[counter].number = 5;
   objects[counter].name = "Glen";
   counter++;//assume counter is global
}
```

Is there any better way to add the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add objects to an array. The size of an array is constant. It remains the same for its entire lifetime.

If you allocate the array dynamically, then what you can do is allocate a new, bigger array, copy the elements from the old one and destroy the old. Such datastructure is called a "resizable array". You can find an implementation of this data structure in the standard library by the name `std::vector`.